# Ajax function doesn't work with dynamic div

Tags: javascript, ajax, onclick

My function for onclick is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mydata').click(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('data'));
    });
});​
```

A static element will work:

```
<div><span id='moreinfo' class='mydata' data="25">Click Me!</span></div>
<div><span id='moreinfo' class='mydata' data="250">Click Me Too!</span></div>
```

But a div pair populated with the same elements dynamically will not fire off the function.  What am I doing wrong?

Code example at: http://jsfiddle.net/KubXr/

Comment: `$(document).on('click', '.mydata', function() { ... });` <- delegated event handlers for **dynamic** elements !

Comment: Holy crap, live() is deprecated, here's the correct answer -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/KubXr/2/), if someone would just have the sense to copy it into an answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need event delegation:

```js
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.mydata', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('data'));
  });
});
```

this means that, any element, existing or future, dynamically added, will have the event triggered if contains the `mydata` class.

Comment: @AspiringAqib - Nope, it may look the same to you, but it is in fact completely different!